# css outline do not extend to include all interior elements when hav absolute elements only in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, absolute, outline

I have test the following code on firefox and work well, but when test it on  chrome the outline did not include all of the elements
 [on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLjwG.png)      [on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOo8H.png)

```js
function ShowHideList(elem) {
    var container = document.getElementById("container")
    var islist = container.getAttribute("islist")
    if (islist == "0") {
        elem.value="Hide"
        container.setAttribute("islist","1")
    } else {
        elem.value="Show"
        container.setAttribute("islist","0")
    }
}
```

```css
.container{
    outline:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
}
.container ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
.container[islist='0'] ul{
    display:none;
}
.container[islist='1'] ul{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container" islist="0">
    <input type="button" onclick="ShowHideList(this)" value="Show" />
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
        <li>item4</li>
        <li>item5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think Chrome is actually right in this case. The ul is positioned in an absolute way, removing it from the flow, so there is no reason for the outline wrap around it.

Comment: thank you, but really I want ul to be absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `ul` is absolutely positioned.  (It's actually surprising that it does work in Firefox.)

Besides that, you could simplify your code by toggling a `classList`:

```
function ShowHideList(elem) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container")
  container.classList.toggle('shown');
  elem.value = elem.value === 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
}
```

```js
function ShowHideList(elem) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container")
  container.classList.toggle('shown');
  elem.value = elem.value === 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
}
```

```css
.container {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.container ul {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.container ul {
  display: none;
}
.container.shown ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container" islist="0">
  <input type="button" onclick="ShowHideList(this)" value="Show" />
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Since the `ul` needs to be absolutely-positioned, you could add a `div` as a child of the container, which is absolutely positioned.  Move the outline to it, and hard-code a height on the container to show the button only.

```js
function ShowHideList(elem) {
  var container = document.getElementById('container'),
      ul = container.querySelector('ul'),
      height;
  
  container.classList.toggle('shown');
  elem.value = elem.value === 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
}
.container div {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
.container ul {
  display: none;
}
.container.shown ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div>
    <input type="button" onclick="ShowHideList(this)" value="Show" />
    <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item3</li>
      <li>item4</li>
      <li>item5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<span>Hiiiiiiiii!</span>
```

Comment: it work but when i toggel ul the position of elemnts beside or bottom of  container  is changed, so i want the positon keep absolute, and ul stay above of elemnts under it,you can add <span>hiiiiiiii</span> after div and test it

Comment: I've added a solution that puts the `ul` inside an absolutely-positioned `div`.